# Android BluetoothSocket write fails on 4.2.2

Tags: java, android, bluetooth

I'm testing on both an ASUS MemoPad HD (4.2.2) and an LG P769 (4.1.2). I wrote a simple program to illustrate my issue:

```
package wat.bluetoothtester;

import java.util.*;
import java.io.*;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.bluetooth.*;
import android.view.*;
import android.util.*;

public class BluetoothTester extends Activity
{
    private final String ADDR = "00:02:72:C6:C2:3C";
    private final UUID _UUID = UUID.fromString("ca444490-3569-4c82-b505-defbc71e9868");

    private BluetoothSocket _socket;

    /** Called when the activity is first created. */
    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
    {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.main);
    }

    public void send(View v){
        try {
            this._socket.getOutputStream().write('x');
        }
        catch (IOException e){
            Log.e("", e.toString());
        }
    }

    public void connect(View v){
        BluetoothAdapter adapter = BluetoothAdapter.getDefaultAdapter();
        BluetoothDevice device = adapter.getRemoteDevice(ADDR);

        try {
            this._socket = device.createInsecureRfcommSocketToServiceRecord(_UUID);
            this._socket.connect();
        }
        catch (IOException e){
            Log.e("", e.toString());
        }
    }

    public void disconnect(View v){
        try {
            this._socket.close();
        }
        catch (IOException e){
            Log.e("", e.toString());
        }
    }
}
```

It blocks, I know, but that's not the issue. Got a simple layout with 3 buttons, as you might be able to guess from the code. I'll post if necessary. I also have a simple Python server running on my computer which just spits out whatever data it receives, and never sends any data.

Anyway, the first time I run this on my 4.2.2 device, it works great. I can connect and disconnect at will, send data, no problem. Now, since I'm developing an app, I have to frequently push a new APK to the device. As soon as I do this, whether or not I disconnect, the writes start failing. The strangest part is that the server actually receives the data and prints it, but the write() calls still block:

```
11-19 12:34:30.127: E/(3484): java.io.IOException: [JSR82] write: write() failed.
11-19 12:34:30.127: E/(3484):   at android.bluetooth.BluetoothSocket.write(BluetoothSocket.java:702)
11-19 12:34:30.127: E/(3484):   at android.bluetooth.BluetoothOutputStream.write(BluetoothOutputStream.java:56)
11-19 12:34:30.127: E/(3484):   at wat.bluetoothtester.BluetoothTester.send(BluetoothTester.java:29)
11-19 12:34:30.127: E/(3484):   at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
11-19 12:34:30.127: E/(3484):   at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
11-19 12:34:30.127: E/(3484):   at android.view.View$1.onClick(View.java:3633)
11-19 12:34:30.127: E/(3484):   at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:4243)
11-19 12:34:30.127: E/(3484):   at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:17520)
11-19 12:34:30.127: E/(3484):   at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:725)
11-19 12:34:30.127: E/(3484):   at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:92)
11-19 12:34:30.127: E/(3484):   at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:153)
11-19 12:34:30.127: E/(3484):   at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5299)
11-19 12:34:30.127: E/(3484):   at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
11-19 12:34:30.127: E/(3484):   at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
11-19 12:34:30.127: E/(3484):   at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:833)
11-19 12:34:30.127: E/(3484):   at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:600)
11-19 12:34:30.127: E/(3484):   at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

So clearly this throws an IOException, even though the data has successfully been sent. This means that the program technically works, but write() blocks the UI for around 10-15 seconds until the exception is thrown. I've tried putting the write() into its own thread, then just creating a TX buffer which it empties at will. This of course doesn't cause the UI to block, but I need to wait for the write() timeout, so that doesn't really help me either. This is the case until I reboot the device. Connect/disconnect both still work fine.

This doesn't happen on my 4.1.2 device, no matter how many times I upload a new APK or kill the process.

I've also confirmed the same problem when using BlueTerm, a terminal-type app for RFCOMM serial connections (actually quite good, plus the source is available).

I've got both devices rooted, and I don't really want to go down this road, but is there a way to restart the Bluetooth service or manually purge the connection pool, or something?

Comment: I have the same issue only on 4.2. Could you find any workaround to get this issue fixed?

Comment: I am also got stuck around this. Has any1 found solution ?

Comment: Hi, same issue here. Have anyone found a solution for that?

Comment: Hi, I have a similar issue. Have you found a solution? Thanks!

Comment: Hey, did you find a solution?

Answer (score 2):

The MediaTek JNI implementation of the [JSR82](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_APIs_for_Bluetooth) for Android doesn't work very well

- [android_server_BluetoothSocketService.cpp](https://github.com/xen0n/android_mediatek_lenovo/blob/9e1f5717d7d17ce4ede26378d7976946e5a1f76e/frameworks-ext/base/core/jni/android_server_BluetoothSocketService.cpp) (writeNative(): Long time no see a goto)
- [BluetoothSocketService.java](https://github.com/xen0n/android_mediatek_lenovo/blob/9e1f5717d7d17ce4ede26378d7976946e5a1f76e/frameworks-ext/base/core/java/android/server/BluetoothSocketService.java)
- [BluetoothSocket.java](https://github.com/xen0n/android_mediatek_lenovo/blob/9e1f5717d7d17ce4ede26378d7976946e5a1f76e/frameworks-ext/base/core/java/android/bluetooth/BluetoothSocket.java)

It creates an array to store the connections context:

```
btmtk_jsr82_mmi_context_struct  g_jsr82MMIContext[JSR82_PORT_NUM];
```

When a new socket is created it uses the fist context position not inUse and unless you close the socket properly (be aware that this is a shared service) the inUse flag is not cleared.

The problem is that only g_jsr82MMIContext[0] seems to receive the EVENT_JSR82_MMI_TX_READY_IND events properly at the end of a write()

The sockets file descriptors seems to be hardcoded and for the socket at g_jsr82MMIContext[0] is 0x8000, so with reflection you can "fake" that socket and close it to clean the g_jsr82MMIContext[0].inUse flag, so next time it will be availabe.

```
    public void connect(View v){

        BluetoothAdapter adapter = BluetoothAdapter.getDefaultAdapter();
        BluetoothDevice device = adapter.getRemoteDevice(ADDR);

        try {
            BluetoothSocket bs = device.createRfcommSocketToServiceRecord(_UUID);
            Field f = bs.getClass().getDeclaredField("mFdHandle");
            f.setAccessible(true);
            f.set(bs, 0x8000);
            bs.close();
            Thread.sleep(2000); // Just in case the socket was really connected 
        } catch (Exception e) {
            Log.e(TAG, "Reset Failed", e);
        } 

        try {
            this._socket = device.createRfcommSocketToServiceRecord(_UUID);
            this._socket.connect();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            Log.e(TAG, "create() failed", e);
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

jla method works well for a single Bluetooth connection.
If there is more than one Bluetooth connection, say two connections, the method disconnects both connections instead of a particular connection.

Anyone have idea to solve for more than one connection case?